# K1 visa - current total wait time for Jacksonville

Tags: k1-visa

In these days I want to apply for a **K1 visa**. I got all the information I need from http://www.visajourney.com/content/k1guide except for a better idea on the total time required (and the I-129F is not mentioned [here](http://www.immihelp.com/processing-times/jacksonville-fl-field-office-processing-times.html) for Florida).

I read around that it can vary from 3 to 18 months but it's quite difficult to make plans with such a flexible timescale.

1. What is the **current average total time** since the US fiance' submits the I-129F form until the beneficiary can **enter the US** with the issued K1?
2. Is it true that when the K1 is delivered to **the beneficiary** the latter **has 6 months to enter the US** plus max 3 months to get married once entered in the US?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Applying from Florida does automatically involve the *Texas Service Center* or could it be processed by the *California Service Center* (way faster!) too? Thanks

Comment: Jacksonville doesn't seem to handle K-1 visas. If you check the various Service Centers [here](https://egov.uscis.gov/cris/processTimesDisplayInit.do). They're currently processing applications dated anywhere from September 28, 2016 to December 2016 so it depends. That doesn't say how long the process itself will take though.

Comment: **Point 2 still unconfirmed**. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

K1 visas are generally processed by these 2 Service Centers:

- Texas -> Average wait for NOA2: about 200 days
- California -> Average wait for NOA2: 30-40 days (but even 3 weeks!)

Destination for K1 visas is quite randomly selected between Texas and California though, doesn't matter where you send it from.
Also, when one center is behind on schedule requests are rerouted/moved to another Service Center.

*NOA2 = Notification Of Action 2 = I-129F processed.

These help too:

- https://rapidvisa.com/k1-visa-timeline/
- https://egov.uscis.gov/cris/processTimesDisplayInit.do
- https://www.soundimmigration.com/how-do-i-check-uscis-processing-times/

Once the K1 visa is granted the couple has 3 months to get married. After the marriage it takes between 2 and 3 months for the work permit and between 6 and 18 months for the Green Card.

Comment: Question *2.* still unconfirmed. Thanks